# A smooth orthonormal basis on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and convergence issue for Schwartz functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\{ \phi_n \}$ be a "smooth" orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I do not impose any other conditions.

Then, for a Schwartz function $f$, can we say more about the convergence of $\sum_n \langle f, \phi_n \rangle \phi_n(x)$ to $f(x)$ than just $L^2$ norm? For example, does the series converge to $f(x)$ pointwise or uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Here $\langle, \rangle$ is the inner product.

I cannot but think of the Fourier transform for the Schwartz functions, but the situation here is much more general. Could anyone help me?

Comment: The Fourier transform of Schwartz functions doesn't quite fit the situation here, unless you talk about functions defined on $[-\pi, \pi]$ instead of on $\mathbb{R}$. In this case $\phi_n(t) = e^{int}$ fits the situation.